# heap corruption detected in destructor

Tags: c++

This is my code i have this error.I think it is a problem with my destructor.
Could you explain me this?
Destructor causes corruption of the heap

```
 #pragma once
 #include<iostream>
 class Adresa
{
char *nume;
int numar;
char *localitate;
public:
Adresa();
Adresa(char *n, int nr, char*l);
Adresa(Adresa &adr);
 void print()
{
    printf("%s %d %s ", nume, numar, localitate);
}
~Adresa();
};
```

and

```
#include "Adresa.h"
#include<iostream>

 Adresa::Adresa()
 {
nume = new char();
localitate = new char();
numar = NULL;
}

Adresa::Adresa(char *n, int nr, char*l)
{      
this->nume = _strdup(n);
this->localitate = _strdup(l);
this->numar = nr;
}      
Adresa::Adresa(Adresa &adr)
{
this->nume = new char(strlen(adr.nume) + 1);
strcpy(nume, adr.nume);
this->numar = adr.numar;
this->localitate = new char(strlen(adr.localitate) + 1);
strcpy(localitate, adr.localitate);
}

Adresa::~Adresa()
{
if (nume != NULL)
{


    delete[] nume;
}
if (localitate != NULL)
{
    delete[] localitate;
}
 }
```

and the output is this
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl3ky.png)

What is the problem with my destructor?

Comment: nume = new char();
localitate = new char();

do not create arrays

Comment: `nume = new char();` ; `delete[] nume;` you allocate member as single `char`, but delete is as array of `chars`

Comment: You might want to consider using a std::unique_ptr instead of any of your raw pointer work though

Comment: @UKMonkey student code, they never allow to use cool adult stuff :)

Comment: Use std::string!

Comment: You are violating the rule of three/five.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had mixed up java and C++. In new expression
 what goes into parents AFTER type-id isn't the size of allocated block, it's a part of initializer.

```
char *s = new char(3);
```

allocates one character and assigns value of 3 to it.

What you had to write

```
char *s = new char[3];
```

only in this case it's legal to use `delete[]`

You can't use normal delete on such pointer. Well, you can but usually you should not, because it leads to undefined behaviour, e.g. will not deallocate whole array on some platforms.

Comment: You are right.Now i notice and want to post it.Thanks:)